# Number of solutions for an equation - sum of variables with limits

Tags: combinatorics

How many solutions are there for the equation: $x_1+x_2+x_3=12$

where: $2\le x_1 \le5$, $0 \le x_2 \le 3$ and $1 \le x_3 \le 4$?

I don't know how to solve it when there are lower and upper limits for the variables $x_1, x_2,  x_3$.

Comment: I suggest you to do a substitution so that $x_1' = x_1 - 2$ so that the lower bound of $x_1'$ becomes zero.

Comment: Here $5+3+4=12<13$. Please check the statement of your problem.

Comment: @RobertZ It doesn't say $x_1 = 5$. It just has lower and upper bounds. It doesn't mean that every number in between those bounds must satisfy the equation, as we are trying to find the number of solutions .... But I believe you are more experienced than I, so am I misinterpreting the question?

Comment: @user477343 I mean that $x_1+x_2+x_3\leq   5+3+4=12<13$.

Comment: @RobertZ ah I see. Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is equivalent enumerate the integer solutions of $y_1+y_2+y_3=9$ where $0\le y_1 \le3$, $0 \le y_2 \le 3$ and $0 \le y_3 \le 3$. So there is just one solution $3+3+3=9$.

If we replace $12$ with $9$ when we have to solve $y_1+y_2+y_3=6$. If $0\leq y_1\leq y_2\leq y_3\leq 3$ then the solutions are:
$$0+3+3=6,\quad 1+2+3=6,\quad 2+2+2=6.$$
and, by symmetry, the total number of solutions is: $3+3!+1=10$.

Comment: You are totally right, and It's one of the tasks on my exam, I guess it's my professor's mistake, or no of solutions is 0.

Comment: I think this is an typo. In order to have a more  significant question change 13.

Comment: Are you able to solve the problem when we replace 12 with 9?

Comment: We use brute force to find the solutions  such that $0\leq y_1\leq y_2\leq y_3\leq 3$. Then we permute them.

Comment: when i get to $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 9$ and $0\le y_1\le y_2\le y_3\le 3$ can I use combinations with repetition (stars and bars problem) formula to calculate number of solutions? ${9 + 3 - 1 \choose 3 - 1}$

Comment: No,  this is not a "stars and bars problem".

Comment: Oh yea, because of the upper limit on each of the $y$'s. Job well done Robert.